# How to download EAR file from Wildfly 10 Web Console

Tags: jboss, wildfly, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I got a new job to maintain a java web application that was already deployed on wildfly 10. They do not have a backup of the application. In wildfly web interface, I found no option for downloading the EAR file.

Please guide me if there any way to download EAR file from wildfly web interface or terminal?

Thanks

**Added Later:**
CLI Attachment command is not available. [image: This is a list of available commands]

Answer (score 1):

You can download the war/ear file using JBoss CLI.

1.
[user@user bin]$ cd /opt/$EAP_HOME/bin/

2.
[user@user bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]

3.
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] ls deployment
test.war

4.
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] attachment save --operation=/deployment=test.war:read-content() --file=/home/user/test.war
File saved to /home/user/test.war

Comment: attachment command is not available. It prompts this "Unexpected command 'attachment'".

please also see this:
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] help --commands
Commands available in the current context:
batch    connect    deployment-info   help    ls    quit    run-batch           undeploy   cd                  connection-info     deployment-overlay  history     module    read-attribute     set      unset   clear     data-source    echo     if     patch    read-operation  shutdown version
command             deploy              echo-dmr     jdbc-driver-info     pwd    reload

Answer (score 0):

In Wildfly 9 there are some folders named data. In them there are some directories with a name in hexadecimal.

Like: `/wildfly/standalone/data/content/0d/bd50f8f78f3e1d99f9eca38a60c4a7d3ed31c8`

Here are a file named content that is a app.

To make sure that it is the file you are looking for, you will have to find an XML where that code is, and it will tell you the name of the application. If you rename it, you can make the backup.

Something like:

```
<deployment name="app.jar" runtime-name="app.jar">
    <content sha1="0dbd50f8f78f3e1d99f9eca38a60c4a7d3ed31c8"/>
</deployment>
```

In my case are standalone.xml, but sometimes it`s domain.xml